# Rotating AV video preview area on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to use the video preview layer on the iPhone and the iPad, but on the iPad it doesn't rotate and it has the wrong height.

Here is the code I have:

```
- (void)capture
{
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                        error:&error];
    if (!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    //Turn on point autofocus for middle of view
    [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
    [device setFocusPointOfInterest:point];
    [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];



    //Add the metadata output device
    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [session addOutput:output];

    NSLog(@"%lu",output.availableMetadataObjectTypes.count);
    for (NSString *s in output.availableMetadataObjectTypes)
        NSLog(@"%@",s);

        //You should check here to see if the session supports these types, if they aren't support you'll get an exception
        output.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode];
        output.rectOfInterest = self.livevideo.bounds;


        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
        newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
        newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
        [self.livevideo.layer insertSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer above:self.livevideo.layer];

    [session startRunning];
}
```

And:

```
- (void)captureFront
{
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                        error:&error];
    if (!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    //Turn on point autofocus for middle of view
    [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
    [device setFocusPointOfInterest:point];
    [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];



    //Add the metadata output device
    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [session addOutput:output];

    NSLog(@"%lu",output.availableMetadataObjectTypes.count);
    for (NSString *s in output.availableMetadataObjectTypes)
        NSLog(@"%@",s);

        //You should check here to see if the session supports these types, if they aren't support you'll get an exception
        output.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode];
        output.rectOfInterest = self.livevideo.bounds;


        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
        newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
        newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;


        [session startRunning];
}
```

[Image](http://s16.postimg.org/m4emubmqt/Foto.jpg)